# wifi connectivity changed broadcast receiver repeats multiple times

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have the following Broadcast receiver.

```
public class TestNetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String TAG = "TEST:";

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED")) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Wifi toggled");

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Network connection changed");

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Network connecion is:" + networkInfo.getTypeName());

                Log.i(TAG, "Detail:"+networkInfo.isFailover());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I toggle the wifi on and off

```
I/TEST:﹕ Wifi toggled
I/TEST:﹕ Network connection changed
I/TEST:﹕ Network connecion is:WIFI
I/TEST:﹕ Detail:false
I/TEST:﹕ Network connection changed
I/TEST:﹕ Network connecion is:WIFI
I/TEST:﹕ Detail:false
I/TEST:﹕ Network connection changed
I/TEST:﹕ Network connecion is:WIFI
I/TEST:﹕ Detail:false

I/TEST:﹕ Network connection changed
I/TEST:﹕ Network connecion is:mobile
I/TEST:﹕ Detail:true
I/TEST:﹕ Network connection changed
I/TEST:﹕ Network connecion is:mobile
I/TEST:﹕ Detail:true
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to know when the connection goes "mobile" or "wifi" and is active but only once. Otherwise it runs my routine 3 or 4 times. I've tried changing networkInfo.whatever() but everything repeats 3 or 4 or more or less times. Is there a way I can just know the connection has changed and what it is only one time somewhere in the receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
public class TestNetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean firstTime = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String TAG = "TEST:";

        if (firstTime) {
            firstTime = false;
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Probably not the most elegand way but it does the trick

Comment: LOL. This is EXACTLY what I ended up doing and you are right it is not elegant at all. Good thing I'm not painting a picture!

Comment: Could you mark it as correct answer? Or at least some upvote :)

Answer (score 4):

The broadcast [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION ] seems to be sticky on few devices hence when you register the receiver it will immediately call onReceive() with the most recently sent broadcast.

Hence it is recommended that you need to do static declaration of receiver on manifest.

This is what i have used :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setMyReceiverStayus(PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    setMyReceiverStayus(PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED);
}


private void setMyReceiverStayus(int receiverState) {
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, MyReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, receiverState,       
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.receiver.MyReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please clarify? I'm not sure I get the idea here. I've created the ComponentName and the Manifest is the same as what I already have but the results are the same. 3x for wifi and 2x for mobile and that will toggle back and forth as I enable/disable wifi.

Comment: basically what i mean is just change you receiver declaration to static in manifest

Comment: Sorry, what do mean by static in this context? If you mean just putting the full name of the receiver, I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

A late post might be useful for someone wanting to do some background activity from connection up/down handler and maintain the thread safety.

I used AtomicBoolean variable,

```
private AtomicBoolean networkUp = new AtomicBoolean(false);

private void onConnectivityUp() {
    Log.d("TAG", "onConnectivityUp");

    if (networkUp.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Duplicate event ignoring
        Log.d("TAG", "onConnectivityUp - ignoring");
    }
}

private void onConnectivityDown() {
    Log.d("TAG", "onConnectivityDown");
    if (networkUp.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Duplicate event ignoring
        Log.d("TAG", "onConnectivityDown - ignoring");
    }
}
```

PS: onConnectivityUp and onConnectivityDown are getting called from my broadcast receiver

Answer (score 1):

When toggling wifi, the broadcast is received many times because of multiple wifi state changes. You can use [getWifiState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getWifiState()) to receive these updates.

You will need to add the permissions  for [ACCESS_WIFI_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_WIFI_STATE), in the manifest file, since app is accessing the wifi state.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<application
    ....
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      ....
    </activity>
</application>
```

Example:

In BroadcastReceiver class,

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("[Broadcast]", "intent - " + intent.getAction());

    switch (intent.getAction()) {
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION:
            ReceivedWifiStateChangedAction(context, intent);
            break;

        default:
            Log.i("[Broadcast]", "Default case!!");
    }
}


private void ReceivedWifiStateChangedAction (Context context, Intent intent) {

    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    switch (wifi.getWifiState()) {

        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
            Log.i("[Broadcast]", "WIFI_STATE_DISABLED");
            break;

        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING:
            Log.i("[Broadcast]", "WIFI_STATE_DISABLING");
            break;

        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
            Log.i("[Broadcast]", "WIFI_STATE_ENABLED");
            break;

        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
            Log.i("[Broadcast]", "WIFI_STATE_ENABLING");
            break;
    }
}
```

In Activity class,

```
private static Receiver myReceiver;

// Register broadcasts
public void RegisterBroadcast () {

    myReceiver = new Receiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
}
```

Output:

When switching on the wifi,

```
I/[Broadcast]: intent - android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
I/[Broadcast]: WIFI_STATE_ENABLING
I/[Broadcast]: intent - android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED
I/[Broadcast]: WIFI_STATE_ENABLED
```

You can discard the  ENABLING/DISABLING broadcast and use ENABLED/DISABLED broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)  
     context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            if (info.isConnected()) {
                // you got a connection! tell your user!
                Log.i("Post", "Connected");

            }
        } 
    }
```

**add this to the manifest**

```
 <receiver android:name="packageName.ConnectivityDetector_Receiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Try this**

Comment: Yes, And I get two replies from connecting to mobil and three from wifi. This is the problem.

Comment: what u want 2 from mobile and 2 from Wifi

Comment: use mine receiver it will be called onconnectivityChanged but it contains checks . if (info.isConnected()) {
               put your code here
            }

Comment: If you look at my original code I also have an isConnected(). My problem is I get 2 isConnected() replies from mobile and 3 from wifi.