# Android WIFI_STATE_CHANGE and STATE_CHANGE fire many times

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver, I use it to know if the phone is connected to Internet via WiFi.

I use it this way

```
<receiver android:name=".InternetReceiver" >
   <intent-filter android:priority="0">
       <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
       <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the InternetReceiver class, I have the code

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    this.intent = intent;

    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if (mWifi != null && mWifi.isAvailable()) 
    {
        if (mWifi.isConnected()) 
        {
            Handler h = new Handler() 
            {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
                {
                    if (msg.what == 1)
                    {
                        getData(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e("Spygen", "No Internet connection");
                    }
                }
            };

            new InternetChecker().isNetworkAvailable(h, 3000);
        }
    }
}
```

Until now, all seems to be perfectly working. Except that, the method getData(1) is fired 3 times simultaneously. In other words, the BroadcastReceiver gets the wifi state changes 3 times.

I passed all day trying to solve it, I tried to use SharedPreferences, but it's not working, since every time the Receiver gets the event, it starts a new AsyncTask, which makes changing SharedPreferences impossible, until all background tasks are done.

What I really want, is firing getData(1) once. Is that anyway to stop receiving after the first call?

Any ideas will be very appreciated

Thank you

Comment: This is an expansion to Alfred's answer with example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69389037/12791298

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think it is better to confirm what state you want to fire getData. Not just rely on the broadcast. As enabling, disabling and any small changes will fire the broadcast. For eg, getWifiState() == WIFI_STATE_ENABLED.